# How do I convert from `pt` to `cm`?

Tags: typst

How do I convert from `pt` to `cm`? I tried multiplying by the proper conversion, and it gives me the expected result, but not without the `pt` still appended to it.

Example:

```
#layout(size => {
  [The page (minus margins) is #size.width wide. \
   In centimeters, that's #{size.width * 0.035277777777778}.]
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is now (since Typst v0.7.0) a native method to perform this conversion (of any absolute length to `cm`): `length.cm()` (along with other similar methods). See here for more info: https://typst.app/docs/reference/types/length/#methods-cm

Note that, as the documentation specifies, the method will fail with an error if the length has non-zero `em` units. For instance, you cannot convert a length such as `3em` or one such as `1pt + 4em` to `cm` directly (through `.cm()`), as the actual length of `3em` or `4em` is not known during code evaluation. This is because `1em` translates to the current font size, whose value depends on where you are in the document, something that isn't known while code is being evaluated.

However, lengths without `em` units will work just fine, e.g. `(2pt).cm()` will return the expected conversion result.

If you have a length with non-zero `em` units and you're not interested in its `em` part, you can just discard the `em` units before conversion with the `abs` field: `(5pt + 3em).abs` returns `5pt`, on which you can use `.cm()`. (For reference: https://typst.app/docs/reference/types/length/)

But, if you *really* need to convert `em` units to `cm`, you will have to convert it to `pt` first by means of `measure`, a function which you can only use inside a `style` element's callback function (the `style` element, in turn, is content, so it must be placed in the document in order to call your code - which makes sense: the style info depends on the document position).
(For more info on these, see the `style` element's documentation at https://typst.app/docs/reference/meta/style/ and the `measure` function's documentation at https://typst.app/docs/reference/layout/measure/)

Here's some sample code showcasing usage of `.cm()` for each case I speak about.

```js
// #(2pt + 3em).cm()  // error if you uncomment (can't convert 'em' to 'cm')

#(2pt + 3em).abs.cm()  // ok (discards the '3em' part, converts 2pt to cm)

#2pt.cm()  // ok (no em units, conversion works fine)

// or we can try to convert the em units to pt / an absolute length,
// and then convert that to cm
#style(styles => {
  // the length we want to convert
  let length = 2pt + 3em

  // its conversion to 'pt'
  // HACK: we create a line of width 'length',
  // and use 'measure' to obtain its width based on
  // the current styles (font size etc.), thus converting
  // our 'em' into a fixed, absolute length.
  let actual-length = measure(line(length: length), styles).width

  // now we can convert the absolute length we got to cm.
  actual-length.cm()
})
```

The Typst code above will produce, on Typst v0.7.0 (using the rendering bot on Discord):

[image: Output of the previous Typst code, consisting of 3 lines (except for the double quotes): "0.07055544776251037", "0.07055544776251037", and "1.2347203358439314"]

Answer (score 0):

From the Discord Q&A (Thanks PgSuper!), I learned that I can remove the unit by dividing by `1pt`, but that sometime in the future it will be native functionality.

Here's how it works:

```
#layout(size => {
  [The page (minus margins) is #size.width wide. \
   In centimeters, that's #{calc.round(size.width * 0.035277777777778 / 1pt)}.]
})
```

[image]